# localhost and 127.0.0.1 doesn't get the same page

Tags: php, localhost

It will show different page when I visit localhost and 127.0.0.1 , I don't know what happened.

My hosts has bind 127.0.0.1 and ::1 to localhost. Like this:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
::1             localhost
```

When I visit localhost it is ok. It shows me the index.php which in the root dir. I want to know why localhost and 127.0.0.1 get the difference page and which file 127.0.0.1 visited?

I use wnmp.

ps: when I ping localhost, it shows me `::1`.
Can anyone help?

Comment: This sounds like a virtual host issue here where the root directory of `localhost` is one place but the root directory of `127.0.0.1` is a different directory. Try looking at your apache config through the wamp interface if you can.

Answer (score 1):

Comment those out in host

```
#   127.0.0.1       localhost
#   ::1             localhost
```

It is predefined already. It is not possible that they are showing different pages since they point to your local ip and the same port 80. Is your wamp fresh installed? you might have configured like the vhost.

Comment: Is it fresh installed?